# How to calculate this probability? sum of chi-square and normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

$$P\left(\sum^{16}_{i=1}(Z+1)^2<k\right)=P\left(\sum Z^2+2\sum Z<k-1\right)$$

Can it be calculate? Is a chi-square + normal a special distribution?

A further question(sorry for the change), without any law of large numbers, would you mind show me the special cases that the sum of distributions are some particular distribution?
(i.e. $X_1,X_2$ are independent, $X_1,X_2$~$Gamma(a,b), X_1+X_2~Gamma(2a,b)$)

Comment: The expansion $\sum (Z+1)^2 = \left(\sum Z^2\right)+2\left(\sum Z\right) + 1$ is not correct. In a correct expansion that last term would be $\sum 1$ rather than just $1$, and that reduces to $n$, not to $1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Oh, sorry for the mistake. But, I still don't understand the answer you provided. How can I use that to calculate this probability?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [noncentral chi-square distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution).